# Problem with making complex query in Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have to make a query in which I should determine if product (wine) belongs to either white wine or red wine type, but here is the catch - table wine has only variety_id and variety table has type_id(red or white). I suppose that I should do it with a subquery but I just can't figure out how with Eloquent methods. Three tables are connected this way: wine can have only one variety and one variety can have multiple wines, one variety can have only one type, while one type can have multiple varieties. How could I check if a wine belongs to either type as that's one of the filters (along with product label, availability and so forth)?

Edit: I tried this but unsuccessfully:

$wines->whereHas('variety.type',function($query){

$query->where('id','=',1);

})->get();

Explanation: I know that id of the red type in Type table is 1 and by this I wanted to get all the red wines

Comment: Dump `Wine::with('variety.type')->get()` and check if your relationships data is loaded.

Comment: I forgot to give update on this topic. It was actually all good the way I posted in the edit. The issue was that I missed the name of the AJAX property.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following relationsips:

In model Wine:

```
public function variety()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Variety::class);
}
```

and in model Variety:

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Type::class);
}
```

you can get what you need with:

```
$colors = ['red', 'white'];
$redAndWhiteWines = Wine::whereHas('variety.type', function ($query) use ($colors) {
    $query->whereIn('name', $typeNames);
})->get();
```

This is considering you have in your types table column name that has the actual color of the wine.